# Why my notification doesn't appear

Tags: android

Hello guys Im using advance notification manager this is the code

```
Notification note = new Notification();
    RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notif);
    contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.drawable.notif);
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, "Focused Crawling");
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, "Crawling In Progress....");
    note.contentView = contentView;

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, LoadingActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    note.contentIntent = contentIntent;
    note.vibrate = new long[] { 500L, 200L, 200L, 500L };
    note.sound = Uri.withAppendedPath(Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "2");
    note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;

    mgr.notify(1337, note);
    startForeground(1337, note);
```

and why it didnt appear at the status bar ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't specify an icon for the status bar, which is required.
Add a line like this to your code:

```
note.icon = R.drawable.youricon;
```

See [Creating a Notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CreateANotification)